Runtime type info for accessing std::variant data
How to access std::variant using std::get by specifying the type info during runtime. Below is a non working code that I tried
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <variant>

class A {
public:
    A(const int a) {
        va = a;
        // below line doesn't compile
        // variant_type = int;
    }

    A(const std::string& a) {
        va = a;
        // below line doesn't compile
        // variant_type = std::string;
    }

    // type variant_type;
    // above line doesn't compile
    std::variant<int, std::string> va{};
};

int main() {
    std::variant<int, std::string> va{"abcd"};
    std::cout << std::get<1>(va) << std::endl;

    va = 23;
    std::cout << std::get<0>(va) << std::endl;

    const A a_obj{1};
    // below line doesn't compile
    // std::get<a_obj.type>(a_obj);

    const A b_obj{"abc"};
    // below line doesn't compile
    // std::get<b_obj.type>(b_obj);
}


Either use std::get with a specific type, or std::visit.

type isn't a type, and types aren't values

Types are not values that you can store in a data member.
In order to access the std::variant data based on its type, you have several options:

Use std::get with a specific type. If you know it at compile-time you can use it plainly. If you want to check the type at runtime before the call to std::get, you can use std::holds_alternative.
Use std::visit with a generic lambda. Will be resolved in runtime.
Use std::visit with a lambda per variant type. This is useful if you need separate logic per type (will be also resolved in runtime).

#include <variant>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    A(const int a) { va = a; }
    A(const std::string& a) { va = a; }
    std::variant<int, std::string> va{};
};

void A_visitor_generic_lambda(A const& a) {
    std::visit([](auto&& arg) { std::cout << arg << std::endl; }, a.va);
}

template<class... Ts>
struct overloaded : Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; };
// explicit deduction guide (not needed as of C++20)
template<class... Ts>
overloaded(Ts...)->overloaded<Ts...>;

void A_visitor_separate_lambdas(A const& a) {
    std::visit(overloaded{
                 [](int arg) { std::cout << arg << std::endl; },
                 [](std::string const& arg) { std::cout << arg << std::endl; } },
               a.va);
}

int main() {
     const A a_obj{ 1 };
     const A b_obj{ "abc" };

    // 1. Use `std::get` with a specific type, after checking the type with `std::holds_alternative`:
    if (std::holds_alternative<int>(a_obj.va)) {
        std::cout << std::get<int>(a_obj.va) << std::endl;
    }
    if (std::holds_alternative<std::string>(b_obj.va)) {
        std::cout << std::get<std::string>(b_obj.va) << std::endl;
    }

    // 2. Use `std::visit` with a generic labmda:
    A_visitor_generic_lambda(a_obj);
    A_visitor_generic_lambda(b_obj);

    // 3. Use `std::visit` with a separate overload lambdas:
    A_visitor_separate_lambdas(a_obj);
    A_visitor_separate_lambdas(b_obj);
}

Output:
1
abc
1
abc
1
abc

Live demo

std::holds_alternative might also worth checking out.

@Raildex good point, added.
